# Dialyxir error order_by doesnt return Ecto.Query.t

Tags: elixir, ecto, dialyzer, typespec

I have this method

```
@spec modify_query(Ecto.Query.t) :: Ecto.Query.t
def modify_query(query) do
  # modifies a Ecto.Query.t
end
```

Then I chain that method with a query:

```
Item
|> where([active: true])
|> order_by([desc: :start])
|> modify_query
```

The code works correctly but apparently for `dialyzer` `order_by` is not returning a `Ecto.Query.t` because it complains with:

> The call 'modify_query'... does not have a term of type atom() |
>   'Elixir.Ecto.Query':t() (with opaque subterms) as 1st argument

If I comment out `# |> order_by([desc: :start])` then `dialyzer` doesnt complain

I have tested through iex the output of:

```
Item
|> where([active: true])
|> order_by([desc: :start])
```

and it says it's data type is Ecto.Query:

```
Term                                                                         
  #Ecto.Query<from r in Item, where: r.active == true, order_by: [desc: r.start]>
Data type                                                                    
  Ecto.Query
```

So how can dialyzer complains??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More info here https://elixirforum.com/t/dialyxir-error-when-using-ecto-query-t-as-function-argument/7491

Basically, order_by is a macro and dialyxir complains about an opaque type.

I think it's fixed in recent versions of Ecto but if you have this issue in older versions of Ecto you can fix it by swapping the calls:

```
Item
|> order_by([desc: :start])
|> where([active: true])
```